# Join two MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I have two simple querys, but i need a little help to join them in one result

```
$query="SELECT * FROM USLUGE WHERE marka='1'";
```

And second query

```
$query2="SELECT * FROM USLUGE WHERE marka='2'";
```

I know the result from $query will give ALL from table USLUGE where marka=1, and result $query2 will give me ALL from table USLUGE wwhere marka=2

But i need to join this two querys in one query, and when i do a WHILE loop, to give me all result from both querys, not a two different WHILE loops, just one WHILE loops with results from both querys?

IS that possible, as example i gave a so simple query to understand :)

Comment: is there any relation between these two tables

Comment: is there any primary-foreign key defined. by join you mean like inner join right join etc? Or by join you mean to combine the 2 results?

Comment: I will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the table structure is the same (more specifically, if both queries return the same number of fields and the same datatypes), you can use SQL `UNION` keyword, for example:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, name FROM table2
```

Note though that if the number of returned columns or datatypes do not match, then attempting to execute the query will result in an error, for example,

```
SELECT id, name, comment FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, name FROM table2
```

will *not* work and will result in an error.

**EDIT:** with a rewritten question, using `OR` or `IN` in the `WHERE` clause is a much better solution:

```
SELECT * FROM USLUGE WHERE marka='1' OR marka='2'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM USLUGE WHERE marka IN ('1', '2');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use union

```
SELECT * FROM USLUGE WHERE marka='1'

UNION

SELECT * FROM USLUGE WHERE marka='2'
```

however you should not use **SELECT *** type the column names instead

The more data is read from the tables, the slower the query will become. It increases the time it takes for the disk operations. Also when the database server is separate from the web server, you will have longer network delays due to the data having to be transferred between the servers.
It is a good habit to always specify which columns you need when you are doing your SELECT’s.

Comment: Works like charms, i know for *, i just added a simple query as example, txanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The question (as edited now) refers to only one table in which case

```
SELECT * FROM USLUGE WHERE marka='1' OR marka='2'
```

Would be better than doing a UNION